# Can I specify the components of FourVector in FeynCalc?

Tags: feyncalc

I'm using FeynCalc to calculate Compton's scattering. I need to use specific values for the components of the photon polarization four-vector. How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you can directly ask the authors of FeynCalc on their forum here: feyncalc.github.io/forum.  I'm sure you'll get helpful pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this problem as well. How I ended up calculating **fully contracted amplitudes** with explicit four-vectors (let it be momenta, polarization vectors) is as follows:

Define the functions

```
Mink[t1_, t2_] := 
  t1[[1]] t2[[1]] - t1[[2]] t2[[2]] - t1[[3]] t2[[3]] - 
   t1[[4]] t2[[4]];
LevContracted[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 Sum[-LeviCivitaTensor[
      4][[mu, nu, alpha, beta]]] a[[mu]] b[[nu]] c[[alpha]] d[[beta]], {mu, 1, 4}, {nu, 1, 4}, {alpha, 1, 
   4}, {beta, 1, 4}];
```

for a Minkowski scalar product and a fully contracted expression with the Levi-Civita-Tensor. Here, I use the signature $(+---)$ and the convention $\epsilon^{0123}=+1$ (to improve readability, I replaced the `\[Mu]` from Mathematica by `mu`). If you then take your four-vectors to be contravariant, you get the additional minus sign in the definition of the second function. I will provide two examples of how to define the four-vectors. We will use lists, as can also be seen from the definition of the functions above. For the momentum of an on-shell particle with mass $m$ in its rest frame, we can define

```
p = {m, 0, 0, 0};
```

and for the three corresponding polarization vectors we use

```
Pol={{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}};
```

i.e. a list of lists, in order to sum over all its polarizations.

Note that when calculating the spin-/polarization-averaged/-summed (I will refer to this as "pol.") squared amplitude and summing over the different polarization states, you have to add them after squaring, i.e.

$|\overset{\sim}{M}| = \frac{1}{(2J_1+1)\ldots (2J_N+1)}\sum_{\{\text{pol. }i\}}{|M_i|^2}$

where $i$ refers to one given polarization state, i.e. every particle has a fixed polarization and $J_i$ are the spins of the particle(s) in the initial state.

Answer (score 1):

```
ScalarProduct[p, q] /. 
  FCI[SP[p, q]] -> {p1, p2, p3, p4}.{q1, -q2, -q3, -q4}
```

I cannot say more.I found this

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it.

`MinkSP[vec1_, vec2_] :=  Times[vec1[[1]], vec2[[1]]] - Times[vec1[[2]], vec2[[2]]] -  Times[vec1[[3]], vec2[[3]]] - Times[vec1[[4]], vec2[[4]]]`